# Cannot open module file: net/sendmail

Tags: lisp, racket

I'm trying to compile this simple racket sendmail code:

```
#lang racket
(require net/sendmail)
(send-mail-message
 "sender@somewhere.com" "Some Subject"
 '("recipient@elsewhere.com" "recipient2@elsewhere.com")
 '("cc@elsewhere.com")
 '("bcc@elsewhere.com")
 (list "Some lines of text" "go here."))
```

But when I compile:

```
racket email.rkt
```

I get this error:

```
cannot open module file
  module path: net/sendmail
```

I thought the sendmail library was builtin? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(require net/sendmail)` works for me, in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you installed "minimal racket", rather than the full "racket" package. This library is part of the "net-lib" package.

To see what packages you have installed, run `raco pkg show -a`.

Here's what I get:

```
hardy:lements> raco pkg show -a | grep net-lib
 net-lib*                     053ca45b223c5...  clone...=net-lib
 planet-lib*                  0110246c9c547...  catalog...et-lib
```

EDIT: if it turns out you *don't* have net-lib installed, you probably want to install the `net` package, per Alexis King's excellent suggestion below:

```
hardy:lements> raco pkg install net
```

Comment: It would be helpful to note how to actually install that package if you don’t have it: run `raco pkg install net-lib`.

Comment: (Although you probably want to `raco pkg install net` so you get the docs, too.)

Comment: Note: `raco pkg show net-lib` is probably easier and avoids grep. See also the `--rx` flag.

Comment: Sam: you're welcome to edit the answer, if you have time. Thanks!